# Is the result of a print or echo a string or can they be number values in php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, string

Can the result of a print or echo in PHP be a number value or is it always a string.
For instance:

this is the PHP code:

```
<?php
    $num = 10;
?>
```

and this is the JS code:

```
function isLarge(number)
{
    var s = document.getElementById("test").value;
    if (s > number)
    {
        window.alert("to large");
        return false;
    }
     return true;
}
```

and this is my other PHP:

```
<input type="text" id=""test>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="isLarge('<?php print $num?>')">
```

My result is not correct if I run this. I thought the `print $num` was giving me a string valued numbers which are not to be compared with a number.

Comment: Where do you give `document.getElementById("test")` a value?

Comment: You do realize your assumption and question are pointless? You ask if echo outputs a string or a number. That is **pointless** to ask. Now as for why: you echo-d something, say `123`. That's a number. but what did you do in your JS: you did `isLarge('123');` -> you *quoted* it. That means you got a string. This is also not on the PHP's side of control. Had you used `isLarge(123);` then you passed **the number** to your JS. As for what the actual thing was in PHP - it's pointless. That means numbers and strings in PHP are not connected to numbers and strings in JS. At all. Ever.

Comment: Also, having mentioned what I did above, I'm giving you a -1 because you have a severe lack of knowledge on topic. This falls under basic of basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is giving you the string representation of `10`, which is also `10`. However, your JS code embeds this inside quotes, making it a JS *string* value. Since the `.value` property of the input element is also a string, JS ends up comparing the two "numbers" as strings and probably giving you unexpected results.

Consider that in JavaScript:

```
2 > 10       ===> false (numeric comparison)
"2" > 10     ===> false ("2" converted to number)
2 > "10"     ===> false ("10" converted to number)
"2" > "10"   ===> true (string comparison!)
```

If you want to compare numbers, then at least one of the two operands to the comparison must be a number.

To convert the `.value` to a number, use `parseInt`:

```
var s = parseInt(document.getElementById("test").value, 10);
```

To convert the PHP variable to a number, you can simply lose the quotes around the PHP echo:

```
onclick="isLarge(<?php print $num?>)"
```

However this could result in a parse error if `$num` is not a number. It would be much better to use the bulletproof solution: `json_encode` to make sure that the value of `$num` safely transitions into JS-land, and then `parseInt` to make it a number:

```
onclick="isLarge(parseInt(<?php print json_encode($num);?>, 10))"
```

With the above technique, the worst case scenario is that if `$num` is garbage you will end up calling `isLarge(0)`.

Comment: thank you it is working fine know after a I have removed the single quote '' from the php print $num

Comment: @DilshatAbduwalli: Sure, but think about the better option: how it works and why. Otherwise it's only a matter of time before you forget some detail and start having problems in similar cases.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any error in the PHP, but I see double quotes in the HTML:

```
<input type="text" id=""test>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I thought the print $num was giving me a string valued numbers which are not to be compared with a number.

PHP is a *loosely typed* language. That means you can cross compare values of different types. If you want to ensure that the correct type is being passed, then you should be using the `===` operator in your JS code.

Echo prints values as a `String`. It is up to you to interpret that value as a number. The single quotes around your output, also tell JS to interpret this value as a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing to do with the PHP

With

```
onclick="isLarge('<?php print $num?>')
```

you are passing the value to Javascript function as a string. Note the `'` single quotes.

If you want to compare as a number remove the `'`

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="isLarge('<?php print $num?>')"
```

The result of this is:

```
onclick="isLarge('10')"
```

`'10'` *in Javascript* is a string, because you put it in quotes *in Javascript*.

PHP *output* is void of any particular type, but it's basically for all intends and purposes a string. What it *really* depends on is how the next entity *reading* this output is interpreting it though.